# BackupManagerService: Unable to finalize restore

Tags: android, xml, android-service, android-backup-service

After an update to an application, I've checked and it seems all user's data was deleted for no apparent reason.
Examining the logcat shows a few suspicious lines:

> 04-11 15:06:17.877 32429-17597/? I/Backup: [GmsBackupTransport] Current restore package : PackageInfo{8f777e2 com.my.package}
>
> 04-11 15:06:17.878 24281-26232/? I/BackupManagerService: Next restore package: RestoreDescription{com.my.package : STREAM}
>
> 04-11 15:06:22.910 24281-32369/? W/RestoreEngine: Restore manifest signatures do not match installed application for com.my.package
>
> 04-11 15:06:27.183 24281-26232/? E/BackupManagerService: Unable to finalize restore of com.my.package
>
> 04-11 15:06:27.184 24281-26232/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.my.package appid=10389 user=0: **clear data**
>
> 04-11 15:06:27.189 24281-24345/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.my.package appid=10389 user=-1: **clearApplicationUserData**
>
> 04-11 15:06:27.225 24281-26232/? D/BackupManagerService: Restore complete, killing host process of com.my.package

When this problem occurs the app's `AndroidManifest` had:

```
android:allowBackup="true"
```

For testing purpose I've generated a new apk with

```
android:allowBackup="false"
```

After changing it to false it doesn't happen.

What can cause this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crucial line is this one:

> Restore manifest signatures do not match installed application.

Which may happen when you backup in release mode and restoring happens in debug mode or vice versa. The exception is thrown in [`BackupManagerService#restoreFinished()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/backup/java/com/android/server/backup/BackupManagerService.java#8562).

In order to manually remove the backup follow [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/69391/how-do-i-cleanup-all-information-backed-up-from-my-phone/69397#69397) steps.

Comment: Thanks!
Do you know of a way to manually remove the backup so I can test this?

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, and your answer really helped me!